# How can I create a style for a control without having to also copy the template?

Tags: templates, styles, expression-blend

For certain controls, the only option I have in Expression Blend is to create a template.  I don't always want to create a template; sometimes I just want to create a style.  I know that I can just take the template out of the style and leave the style in place.  But then if I ever want to change the style I have to go to it directly in the resource dictionary; I can no longer use "Edit Current". It just seems clunky (and wasteful) that I have to create a copy of the template just so I can associate a style with a control.  After all, creating a template in expression blend creates a style.  It seems that I should be able to just create a style.  Is there a way to do this?  Is there a reason that I cannot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What control can you not create a Style for? Did you try the Object > Edit Style menu?  It has Edit Current, Edit a Copy, Create Empty, and Apply Resource options. (Be sure you have the correct object type selected).

If that doesn't help, post some more specifics and I'll try to help.

Comment: Oh, brilliant. Why can't they put that in the context menu? Its so funny. I never use the main menu in any tool that I use.